# Ladder/Eggs test for an infinite ladder and an infinite number of eggs

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

You all know the problem with the ladder and the eggs in which you need to find the heighest rung from which a dropped egg doesn't break.

The problem is explained on stackoverflow for the case with 100 rungs and 2 eggs, but how about when you have an infinite ladder? (and of course an infinite number of eggs)

How would you approach the problem in this case? Is Fibonacci search a solution?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: [One-sided search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#One-sided_search) finds the highest rung with O(log f) drops, where that rung is floor f. I'm posting this as a comment because it's not clear how you want to compare algorithms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For infinite eggs and ladder of unknown height, I would go with exponential search (check rung 1, then rung 2, then 4, 8, 16, etc.) until an egg breaks. If the rung on which the egg breaks is N, then do binary search between rungs N and N/2.